# ReportEvent not working for posting critical category events

Tags: winapi

I need to report an event that comes under critical category.
Rest is working fine but i am having problems with using the ReportEvent for posting "critical" category event.
Code sample is something like:

`const WORD LM_NT_LOG_CATEGORY_CRITICAL = 1;`

```
WORD category;

category = LM_NT_LOG_CATEGORY_UNKNOWN;

ReportEvent(hEventSource,logLevel,category, event,NULL,2,0,
                    (const TCHAR**) &lpszStrings,
                    NULL);
```

In Windows Event Viewer for this particular event i see a "1" in Category column instead of "critical".
Can anyone please help me?

Comment: Take a look at this - the second answer may be relevant  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1290782/where-can-i-find-a-good-example-of-reportevent-function-usage

Answer (score 0):

In order to get strings displayed in the Event Viewer you have to provide (and possibly localize) a mapping from your numeric categories.  The rules are [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363649%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

> Categories can be stored in a separate message file, or in a file that
>   contains messages of other types. If you create a single message file,
>   be sure that the categories are the first messages in the file.